# No sign of graphics card in 16.04

Tags: 16.04, drivers, amd-graphics

When I tried

```
$ inxi -Fxz
```

There was an entry about the graphics card as shown below

```
Card-2: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD/ATI] Whistler [Radeon HD 6630M/6650M/6750M/7670M/7690M] bus-ID: 01:00.0
```

There is no mention of 1GB graphics card in **About this computer** in the core, nor in tools like *Stacer* or **Additional Drivers**

Does this mean that graphics card is not working?

Comment: What graphics card are you looking for ?

Comment: You have a hybrid graphics system, and the on-board Intel GPU is probably being used. Hence why the AMD discrete GPU is "Card-2" here.

Comment: Why the downvote, seems to be a reasonable question to me

Comment: Yes, onboard Intel GPU is in use. I do some graphics. My system hangs often and now I know why. Is it because my graphics card has no support on 16.04 and there is no fix available for it ? Thanks.